# Bootstrap Formwizard - Prevent to scroll to next step if each page form submitting ajax response gets error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, formwizard

I am using twitter bootstrap form wizard to submit data on each page with validation. Now i want to prevent, scroll to next step if ajax response gets error while submitting data. Below is my code,

```
'onNext': function(tab,navigation,index){
    //scrollTo('#wizard',-100);
    if(index == 1){
        var $valid = $('#register_form').valid();
        if(!$valid){
            $validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var options = $('form[name=register_form]').find('input, textarea, select').filter('.fw1').serialize();
            var data = options + '&step=1';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'employeeEntryProcess.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    this.show(2);
                },
                error: function(){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working after changes. Thanks to all for helping.

```
  'onNext': function(tab,navigation,index){
        if(index == 1){
          var $valid = $('#register_form').valid();
          if(!$valid){
            $validator.focusInvalid();
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            var options = $('form[name=register_form]').find('input, textarea, select').filter('.fw1').serialize();
            var data = options + '&step=1';
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'employeeEntryProcess.php',
              data: data,
              success: function(response){
                 $('#wizard').bootstrapWizard('show',1);
              },
              error: function(){
                 alert('Error');
             }
          });
       }
   }
   return false;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to always `return false` so that it doesn't scroll to next step automatically, and then manually scrolling to the next step in the `success` function of the AJAX request (so that it would only proceed if it was successful). You may want to put an animation for the duration of the AJAX request as otherwise it would look like nothing is happening.

Comment: @VenkateshAnantharaj Don't put return false in the error function, put it in the onNext event handler.

Comment: I tried but it prevents to scroll next even ajax response get success. Can You please correct my code if i have any error in this.

Comment: @VenkateshAnantharaj I have made a jsFiddle for you based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/c9q6ga5L/

Comment: @VenkateshAnantharaj Sorry, wrong link, here's the updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/c9q6ga5L/4/